# Using sscanf() to take specific input to do a command with if statement?

Tags: c

I have been trying to try to figure out if I could use `sscanf(3)` to get a users input to do a command. In this case if they enter "exit", I want the program to terminate. I tried this...

```
    char exitNow[100];

    if(sscanf("exit", "%s", exitNow))
    {
        exit(0);
    }
```

For some reason this will not terminate the program. If I put the `exit(0)` anywhere else it will terminate the program so I am convinced it is my `sscanf(3)`

Any suggestions? I want to learn `sscanf(3)` a bit more and see what it is capable of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong function for what you are trying to do.  Assuming exitNow is filed by input somewhere else, you probably want:

```
if (!strcmp(exitNow, "exit"))
    exit(0);
```

Comment: Ahh, I always forget about `strcmp` (spent hours trying to use `isalpha` to check for user input). Love this function, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What sscanf does is read the input from a string, unlike scanf which reads it from stdin (user input). There's no user input, just a string.

So what your code does is reads a string (You specified it with %s) and puts it in exitNow. The string which sscanf reads the input from is "exit". So what it does is putting "exit" in exitNow.

sscanf returns the amount of tokens it successfully reads, which in this case is 1.
So it should enter in exit(0); always

The code you want is this:

```
int main (void) {
        char userInput[255];

        //Read user input
        fgets(userInput, 255, stdin);

        //Check user input
        //strncmp checks the (now) 4 first characters
        //and returns 0 if first string and second string
        //equals on those first 4 characters.
        if (!strncmp(userInput, "exit", 4)) {
                printf("User wants to exit!\n");
        }
        else {
                printf("User doesn't want to exit, but program is over!\n");
        }

}
```

Comment: Oh okay, I understand that now. I always thought I could use sscanf for this purpose. If I wanted to split up exit with a comma could I do that with sscanf to insert the commas?

Comment: You mean adding text after the command? Sure!
sscanf(input, "%s, that's what user put!", anotherstring);

But it's much easier if you use a function like strcat for this scenario.